# which one is given more preference for JavaScript or CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

here is my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            color:red;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        window.onclick = function(){
            document.getElementsByTagName("body").color="blue";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    here is some text for test
</body>
```

when i run it in my browser (initially it is red) and click in window it doesn't respond to click i mean it should change the color of text from red to blue but nothing happens. Where am i wrong?

Comment: js and css does not compete with each other, what you are doing is essentially javascript applying css to an html element, this means that its still css, that type of css is called inline css, . As others have said inline css has more precendence over normal css except if you use !important in your css rules.

Comment: I suppose, it must be `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.color="blue";`

Comment: @Mr_Green or, `document.body`.

Comment: ya I was confused by OP's code. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:-

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PdEba/)

This will add style attribute to the body element, which will override the css rule.

```
window.onclick = function(){
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.color="blue";
    }
```

It should be `style.color` as `color` is a property of `style` property of element and even though it is `body` `.getElementsByTagName` returns a collection so you need to use `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]` to get the element and apply style to it.

**And yes styles applied the element direclty will override the class css rule**

Comment: thnaks buddy i got the bug.. getElementByTagName returns array not a single object Now it is working

Comment: +1. The only answer so far to actually fix the problem with the OP's code. (Though it wouldn't hurt to add an explanation.)

Answer (score 2):

**Style property has more precedence** over styles applied by class.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body").color="blue";
```

**This has more preference**

Also color is a property of style attribute.

So your style should have looked something like this as `getElementsByTagName` returns a node list.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.color="blue";
```

it is a better idea to use classes instead, cause it is lot cleaner.

Comment: That's not an "inline style".

Comment: What I meant by inline style here is that it gets added directly on the element . I think I need to rephrase my words

Comment: _"So it is better to use classes..."_ - If you remove the "so" I would agree, but saying "so it is better" implies you've just proven the case - which you have not. (Also you didn't explain why the OP's code doesn't work.)

Comment: can we say that whichever comes last got more preference in such styling cases?(As it is in CSS)?

Comment: Then comes the question of `specificity`

Answer (score 1):

**Inline CSS is more powerful and overrides CSS defined anywhere else**.As far as working of your code, I modified it a little bit like this:

```
window.onclick = function(){
        //document.getElementsByTagName("body").color="blue";
document.body.style.color="blue";
    }
```

**[DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/3zTgD/)**

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your JS. `getElementsByTagName` returns a NodeList (which is like an array), not a single element. You need to set the property on an element, not a NodeList. For example:

```
document.body.color="blue";
```

Setting the `color` property of the body element (IIRC, it's been a very long time since I went near that part of HTML) is equivalent to setting the `color` attribute. This is an obsolete presentational hint attribute.

The [CSS specification says](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#preshint):

> The UA may choose to honor presentational attributes in an HTML source document. If so, these attributes are translated to the corresponding CSS rules with specificity equal to 0, and are treated as if they were inserted at the start of the author style sheet. They may therefore be overridden by subsequent style sheet rules. In a transition phase, this policy will make it easier for stylistic attributes to coexist with style sheets.

So the style specified in the stylesheet should continue to apply.

On the other hand, setting a `style.something` property is equivalent to modifying the `style` *attribute* on an element.

```
document.body.style.color="blue";
```

In the cascade, `!important` declarations aside, [properties set via the `style` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) are most specific.

So of those two rules, the blue one would win.

Comment: This type of answers make me believe that no matter how much i know, i still dont know much :(, anyways thanks for wonderful explanation.

Answer (score 0):

JS inserts the changes inline, giving them pretty much the highest priority, unless you have !important in your css.

Check to see if you code (document.getElementsByTagName("body").color="blue";) works from the dev console (F12 for Chrome). There appears to be a problem with it. I can't help debug, however, as I usually do such actions via jQuery, and vanilla JS color changes are unintuitive for me.

Answer (score 0):

js and css does not compete with each other, what you are doing is essentially javascript applying css to an html element, this means that its still css, that type of css is called inline css, . As others have said inline css has more precendence over normal css except if you use `!important` in your css rules

As to why your code is not working, because you are doing it wrong.

Change 
`document.getElementsByTagName("body").color="blue";`
To
`document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.color = 'blue';`

Here's a jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/n2kqd/